# Providing default population to "Library/Application support" folder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, filesystems, assets

I'm writing an iOS app which needs a ~60MB resource file to work correctly. I would like to provide this file with the app itself, so it can work straight after installing it from the store without downloading extra data at the first launch.

I also want to be able to update such file by downloading a new version of it from a specific URL. I thought the most appropriate folder to store this file would be "Library/Application support", as specified in the [guidelines provided by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) itself.

My problem is that I can't find a way to provide the "Library/Application support" folder with a default population using xcode 9. I don't want to have multiple copies of this file around to avoid wasting space, and I want the possibility to update this file to a newer version, overwriting / replacing the old one.

This might be a newbie question (I'm a newbie of iOS development) but I really couldn't find anything related to pre-populating that folder.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete anything from your distribution bundle. It's just not allowed.

So you options are:

1. Distribute the resource with the app, and create a **copy** in "Library/Application support".
2. **Don't** include the resource with the app, and download it on first run.
3. You didn't say *what* the resource is, so I don't know if this would be an option, but... Include only a *portion* of the resource with the app, copy it into "Library/Application support" and "update it" on first run.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The resource is a package containing images, sounds, json files and so on. It would be technically possible for me to create a "minimal" package and use that to create the gui to download the full package, though it would require a download when first launching the app which I wanted to avoid. It looks like it's impossible to achieve exactly the architecture I had in my mind